# Basic ARM application in Xilinx Zynq SoC

Tags: arm, fpga, xilinx, zynq, system-on-chip

I am new to Xilinx Zynq SoC. Zynq has ARM(dual cores). I am curious if it is possible to run program C/C++ program only on ARM processors without using the FPGA fabric. My research could not helped much.

IF yes, I would like to know some basic steps that I need to follow to achieve the goal.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? I'm pretty sure you're using the ARM processor by default anyway unless you're specifically synthesising logic for the FPGA and uploading it via the ARM processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Tutorial by Xilinx.

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_3/ug873-zynq-ctt.pdf.

It is clearly stated in section 5.2.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run your own application code without using the FPGA fabric.

You can download the xilinx SDK http://www.xilinx.com/tools/sdk.htm and start by trying some of the hello world projects available. Adding a FPGA bitstream is optional.